# Where is the node created timestamp stored in the database?

Tags: 8, entities, nodes, database

I need to create an SQL query that finds all nodes of a certain type created X days ago, so I can get their IDs. Due to the massive number of nodes in the database, I would prefer to use a direct SQL query, rather than entityQuery. I was warned entityQuery can be slow if working with large volumes of data.

Anyway, I need to find where is the node created timestamp stored in the database. In Drupal 7, it is stored directly in the node table, but not in Drupal 8.

Comment: You can directly query the 'node_field_data' table but honestly the difference in performance with entityQuery will be small if you are setting a limit on the number of rows returned as you should if you want to do this in a single request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The created date is stored in the `node_field_data` table as a UNIX timestamp in a cloumn called `created`.

Here's the code you would use to fetch the nodes that has been created X days ago, using a direct select query.

```
$day = 86400; // One day in seconds.
$days = 3; // The amount of days ago to fetch from.

$nids = \Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data', 'n')
  ->addField('n', 'nid')
  ->condition('n.created', \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime() - $days * $day, '>')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();

$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);
```

Make sure to inject the `database` and the `entity_type.manager` services (if possible) when implementing the code yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you go into your Drupal database you should find a table called 'node_field_data'. In this table there is a column labeled 'created'. That will be your Unix timestamp for when the node was created.